# Words the Holy Ghost teaches with

Tags: comparative-christianity, spiritual-gifts

Is there a compilation of Biblical words in which the Holy Ghost teaches with?

Comment: I have edited and quoted your reference as I think you are referring to verse 13, primarily. Welcome to SE-C. Please see the Tour and Help (below, left) as to the purpose and the functioning of the site.

Comment: @ClementBaptiste Feel free to contact me through my profile wherein is  my email address. Kind Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say, Yes, definitely.

For example the word 'redemption' has a common meaning in the English language and is used in regard to mortgages and financial transactions. It is also used in a very loose way meaning that one can 'redeem' oneself from a bad mistake by correcting that mistake.

But in scripture we see two Hebrew words in the Old Testament scripture translated 'redeem' - *gaal* and *padah*. These two words are related and have precise meanings.

Then in the New Testament Greek scripture we see two sets of words, which relate to the two Hebrew words. One set of Greek words is *agorazo/exagorazo*. The other set is *lutron/lutrosis/apolutrosis*.

I am not going to go into all this as this answer is not about 'redemption' as such : it is about how words are used.

If one studies the very logical setting out (by the Holy Spirit who inspired all of scripture) of the two Hebrew words and the two sets of Greek words, one will come to an understanding of what we call (in the English language) 'redemption'.

Strictly speaking, we need two words to describe 'redemption' since there are two Hebrew words and two sets of Greek words.

But it is, in my view, sufficient (for the time being until we can really sort this out properly) to at least be aware of what is there in scripture, so that we can be intelligent in our reading of it.

This is a word (strictly speaking - two words) which the Holy Spirit would have us to understand. I would say.

---

I study the KJV myself and I have found Young's Analytical Concordance an invaluable tool. All of the above (regarding the word 'redemption') is set out, very neatly and simply, in the two halves of Young's Concordance, the first half being a list of the English words used in the bible and the second half being a Hebrew/Greek lexicon (that is all written in both anglicised letters and original letters) so that one can see the different English words that a particular Hebrew/Greek word has been translated into.

Without Robert Young's extensive lifelong labours, or the equivalent, such as I would not have been able to write this answer at all.

Comment: Thanks for showing that the "spiritual" words are those of the Bible, and not some other magical or mystical language!

Comment: @curiousdannii Well, it is good to bear in mind that for every deed, every word and for every action, we will give an account thereof, at the judgment seat of Christ, in the day of the Son of man.

Comment: Thank you Nigel J for the answer and the Yong's concordance reference.

Comment: @ClementBaptiste You are most welcome. The Lord bless thee.